# Fetch record from two different table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named

1.Table A

2.Table B

I am giving the in table details below :

Table A :

```
======================
   id  |   Name  |
======================
   1   |   Blue  |
======================
   2   |   Green |
======================
   3   |   Red   |
======================
   4   |   Yellow|
======================
   5   |   Black |
======================
   6   |   Orange|
```

Table B :

```
================================
  id |  table_id  |  value   |
================================
  1  |   1        |   x      |
================================
  2  |   2        |   z      |
================================
  3  |   3        |   W      |
```

Using this two tables,I want to display the values comes from two tables like below :

```
 SL      |    Name   |
------------------------
 1       |    Blue   |
------------------------
 2       |    Green  |
------------------------
 3       |    Red    |
------------------------
 4       |    Yellow |
------------------------
 5       |    Black  |
------------------------
 6       |    Orange |
```

Above the view,Bold(Blue,Green,Yellow) means Table B consists the value Table A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query something like below :

```
$query = mysql_query("Select *from table A LEFT JOIN table B ON a.id=b.table_id");
while ($newRow = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   if $newRow['table_id']!=NULL
   { 
       //You should white your bold code
   }
   else
   {
       //others
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN:

```
select *
from A left join B on A.id=B.id
```

Then, in PHP, you print in bold any row for which

```
$row['table_id']!==null;
```

Comment: Fetching wrong data,please see my above giving table.id from table Table A is related with table_id in table B.May be your condition in query should be  A.id=b.table_id @ hammurabi,Anyway thanks for the reply.